# Pattern cut out areas again with even odd rule

Tags: tikz-pgf, pattern, hobby

I have a litle trouble with the "even odd rule". I would like to draw the picture below which isn't the problem. The problem is, that i would need to have the little white spots, where the "hobby-line" cuts itselfs out, also to have the pattern.

I am working with the code below.

Please excuse the complicated definition of the coordinates, but this is part of a bigger picture and it was much easier to just make it work on its own then writing it independently.

If you have any questions about things you need to know please ask :)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, patterns, hobby}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, use Hobby shortcut]
        \def \abstand {1}

        \coordinate (Anfang Kurve) at (0,0);

        \coordinate (H1) at ($(Anfang Kurve) + (0.5*\abstand, 0.2*\abstand)$);
        \coordinate (H2) at ($(H1) + (1*\abstand, -0.15*\abstand)$);
        \coordinate (H3) at ($(H2) + (0.75*\abstand, 2.35*\abstand)$);
        \coordinate (H4) at ($(H3) + (0.4*\abstand, -2*\abstand)$);
        \coordinate (H5) at ($(H4) + (0.1*\abstand, -1.2*\abstand)$);
        \coordinate (H6) at ($(H5) + (-0.75*\abstand, 0.4*\abstand)$);
        \coordinate (H7) at ($(H6) + (-0.4*\abstand, 0.5*\abstand)$);
        \coordinate (H8) at ($(H7) + (-0.8*\abstand, 0.1*\abstand)$);

        \draw[pattern = north west lines, even odd rule] (Anfang Kurve) .. (H1) .. (H2) 
            .. (H3) .. (H4) .. (H5) .. (H6) .. (H7) .. (H8) .. (Anfang Kurve)
        (Anfang Kurve) --+ (2*\abstand, 0) --+(2*\abstand,2*\abstand) 
            --+ (3*\abstand, 2*\abstand) --+ (3*\abstand, -1*\abstand) 
            --+ (\abstand, -1*\abstand) --+ (\abstand,0) --+ (0,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: result of the text above]
[image: areas with the problem]

Thanks in advands for any kind of help. :)

Comment: If I understood correctly, you would like the inside of the areas you have surrounded in red to be filled with the same pattern (north-east lines). Is that it?

Comment: Thats exactly what I want

Comment: Ok, please make your code compileable.

Comment: and done, please excuse the time it took. I hade quite some other work to do

Comment: The small white spots are irrespective of `even odd rule`, i.e. they stay even if you drop that key. Please consider tagging your question `tikz-pgf` such that it gets more attention.

Comment: i am not shure i get what you are saying. I have just tried to take the even odd rule out, but then the "big" white spot disapears.

Thanks for the suggestion with the tag. :)

Comment: @Kai Yes, that's what I was trying to say: the issue has nothing to do with `even odd rule`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you encounter has nothing to do with `even odd rule`, i.e. the small white spots will remain if you drop the key. One way to solve the issue is to employ the pgfplots `fillbetween` library.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,hobby,patterns}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, use Hobby shortcut]
    \def \abstand {1}

    \coordinate (Anfang Kurve) at (0,0);

    \coordinate (H1) at ($(Anfang Kurve) + (0.5*\abstand, 0.2*\abstand)$);
    \coordinate (H2) at ($(H1) + (1*\abstand, -0.15*\abstand)$);
    \coordinate (H3) at ($(H2) + (0.75*\abstand, 2.35*\abstand)$);
    \coordinate (H4) at ($(H3) + (0.4*\abstand, -2*\abstand)$);
    \coordinate (H5) at ($(H4) + (0.1*\abstand, -1.2*\abstand)$);
    \coordinate (H6) at ($(H5) + (-0.75*\abstand, 0.4*\abstand)$);
    \coordinate (H7) at ($(H6) + (-0.4*\abstand, 0.5*\abstand)$);
    \coordinate (H8) at ($(H7) + (-0.8*\abstand, 0.1*\abstand)$);
    \draw[pattern = north west lines, even odd rule,name path=curve] 
    (Anfang Kurve) .. (H1) .. (H2) 
            .. (H3) .. (H4) .. (H5) .. (H6) .. (H7) .. (H8) .. (Anfang Kurve)
        (Anfang Kurve) --+ (2*\abstand, 0) --+(2*\abstand,2*\abstand) 
            --+ (3*\abstand, 2*\abstand) --+ (3*\abstand, -1*\abstand) 
            --+ (\abstand, -1*\abstand) --+ (\abstand,0) --+ (0,0);
    \path[name path=hori] (Anfang Kurve) --+ (2*\abstand, 0);
    \path[pattern = north west lines,
    intersection segments={of=curve and hori,sequence={A2}}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that absolutely solves my problem :)

thank you very much for your effort and the quick respond :)